# Explain line of C code in qsort

Tags: c, syntax, qsort

I've been looking at different implementations of qsort, and there's a line in the source found here (https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html) that I don't understand.  It looks like a function pointer declaration.  I'd appreciate any help.  I've included as much code as necessary (with the line noted) to I think answer the question.  Please let me know if not, thanks.

```
typedef struct
{
    char *lo;
    char *hi;

} stack_node;


void _quicksort (void *const pbase, size_t total_elems, size_t size, cmp_t cmp, void *arg)
{

    char *base_ptr = (char *) pbase;

    const size_t max_thresh = 4 * size;

    if (total_elems == 0)

        return;

    if (total_elems > 4)
    {
        char *lo = base_ptr;
        char *hi = &lo[size * (total_elems - 1)];
        stack_node stack[(8 * sizeof(size_t))];
        stack_node *top = stack;

        /* Line below is a function pointer declaration?  Initializes struct? */

        ((void) ((top->lo = (((void*)0))), (top->hi = (((void*)0))), ++top));

        while ((stack < top))
        {
            char *left_ptr;
            char *right_ptr;

            char *mid = lo + size * ((hi - lo) / size >> 1);
```

... code goes on

Comment: The code at your link does not have such line. It just says `PUSH (NULL, NULL);`. Where did you obtain this version and why are you even looking at it in this form?

Comment: The code above is post preprocessing

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not a function pointer declaration. It is just a convoluted way to say

```
top->lo = 0;
top->hi = 0;
++top;
```

You can rewrite the above as a single expression statement using `,` operator

```
top->lo = 0, top->hi = 0, ++top;
```

then add unnecessary casts

```
top->lo = (void *) 0, top->hi = (void *) 0, ++top;
```

and a bunch of redundant `()`s

```
(top->lo = (((void *) 0))), (top->hi = (((void *) 0))), ++top;
```

and then cast the whole thing to `(void)` (say, to suppress any potential compiler warnings about expression result's being "unused")

```
((void) ((top->lo = (((void *) 0))), (top->hi = (((void *) 0))), ++top));
```

and now you have your original version.

Why someone decided to use that strange syntax with `,` operator and massive amount of redundant `()` is not clear to me. Looks like a macro expansion. Maybe it is a piece of already-preprocessed code? The `((void *) 0)` parts might easily be preprocessor replacements for standard `NULL` macro.

Comment: That helps a lot.  Thanks.  It is post macro expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the URL we discover that the line is actually a macro definition in particular

```
/* The next 4 #defines implement a very fast in-line stack abstraction. */
/* The stack needs log (total_elements) entries (we could even subtract
   log(MAX_THRESH)).  Since total_elements has type size_t, we get as
   upper bound for log (total_elements):
   bits per byte (CHAR_BIT) * sizeof(size_t).  */

#define STACK_SIZE        (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(size_t))
#define PUSH(low, high)   ((void) ((top->lo = (low)), (top->hi = (high)), ++top))
#define POP(low, high)    ((void) (--top, (low = top->lo), (high = top->hi)))
#define STACK_NOT_EMPTY   (stack < top)
```

and the code actually appears in the definition of `PUSH`  and its compendium appears in `POP`.  The use of extra `()`s is to ensure that `++top` and `--top` happen `inline` and in the correct sequence.

The reason it's implemented this way is clearer when we see the *Copyright (C) 1991 - 2017* message at the top of the `qsort.c` ... Compilers in 1991 were probably really sucky at inlining functions.